# Crypto++ Errors In cryptlib.h

Tags: c++

Errors when compiling project that includes Crypto++ cryptlib.h

```
cryptlib.h(1200, 15): [C2059] syntax error: 'do'
cryptlib.h(1200, 15): [C2334] unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
cryptlib.h(1200, 15): [C2059] syntax error: 'while'
cryptlib.h(1201, 3): [C2334] unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
cryptlib.h(1217, 34): [C2059] syntax error: 'do'
cryptlib.h(1217, 3): [C2143] syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
cryptlib.h(2961, 15): [C2059] syntax error: 'do'
cryptlib.h(2961, 15): [C2334] unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
cryptlib.h(2961, 15): [C2059] syntax error: 'while'
cryptlib.h(2961, 70): [C2238] unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Edit: Line 1200 and 1201

```
virtual bool Verify(const byte *digest)
    {return TruncatedVerify(digest, DigestSize());}
```

Edit 2: Line 1216 and 1217

```
virtual bool VerifyDigest(const byte *digest, const byte *input, size_t length)
    {Update(input, length); return Verify(digest);}
```

Line 2961

```
virtual bool Verify(PK_MessageAccumulator *messageAccumulator) const;
```

Comment: Please include a few lines of code around `cryptlib.h(1200, 15)` in the question as the online source https://github.com/doo/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptlib.h#L1200 looks like it is out of sync with your copy.

Comment: its the most recent version from [The website i found when searching for Crypto++](https://cryptopp.com/#download)

Comment: Check the your project for `#define`s that might redefine commonly used names both in your source/header files and in the command line options; as this looks macro substitution gone wrong.  If this does not find anything then get the compiler to output the pre-processed file and compare to the original.

Comment: There is no defines in my project